# Using vim Sessions Only With GUI?

Tags: vim

My usage-scenario may seem a bit unusual, but here it is: When using vim (it's one of about 4 different editors I use regularly), I use it in two different situations. The first is via the GUI, in which I'll have multiple buffers and have some settings different than when I use it from the command-line (by testing "`if has('gui_running')`"). The other is when I need to do something short-and-quick, from the command-line, such as make a small change to a dot-file or other type of config.

What I would *like* to do, is have sessions enabled for the GUI, but have any command-line invocations ignore them. That is, I don't want to bring up the full existing session on a CL invocation, nor do I want it (and whatever buffer/file it involved) to alter the session that the GUI is using. As I'm fairly new to the post-vi-functionality of vim, I'm not really sure how to pull this off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do your session magic in your `.gvimrc` and everything else in your `.vimrc`.  The GUI will source both, but the CL version will only source the `.vimrc`.

The session magic is to set up autocommands to write your session to a file on exit, and reload it by sourcing the file upon entrance.

```
au VimLeave * mksession ~/.gvimsession
au VimEnter * source ~/.gvimsession
```

Comment: This does the trick, though I don't have to create a .gvimrc to use it-- it works fine within the GUI-only block of my .vimrc.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to add a ! to mksession so that you won't get an override error message upon exiting everytime.

```
au VimLeave * mksession! ~/.gvimsession
au VimEnter * source ~/.gvimsession
```