# In .vimrc, how to test whether any filename arguments are given to Vim at invocation?

Tags: vim

The answer to the question
[Using vim Sessions Only With GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330562/using-vim-sessions-only-with-gui) suggests using

```
au VimLeave * mksession! ~/.gvimsession
au VimEnter * source ~/.gvimsession
```

My problem is when I start Vim, say, by issuing `$ gvim test.html`, the `test.html` file is loaded into a buffer that is not shown.

How can I test if arguments where passed and not execute the `au VimEnter` in such a case?
Or, alternatively, how can I switch to the buffer holding the file with the given file name.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One can test whether there are any command-line arguments (using the
`argc()` function) and load the previously saved session only when
there are not any:

```
:autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 | source ~/.gvimsession | endif
```

Comment: Vim is such a over-complete application. We never stop learning. There is always a new function or command to discover. Personally, I'd never imagine that Vim had a `argc()` function — maybe I need to read `:h function-list` and `:h index` more often. I wonder if Bram knows what his program is capable of doing, if so he deserves a Nobel Prize.

Comment: @sidyll: By the way, `:h argument-list` is worth reading to get information about argument list in Vim.