# Is there any way in Vim to test that I have no file opened at start?

Tags: vim

At the end of my `.vimrc` I want to conditionally launch a command opening my TODO list.

The problem is that I only want that behaviour when I am using `vim` or `gvim`.

And currently, I also load that buffer if I launch `vim foo.bar`, which is pretty inconvenient because I have to switch back to `foo.bar`

So basically I want to be able to write something like :

```
 if (some condition telling me that I am on the defaut buffer)
     silent LaunchTaskList
 endif
```

Comment: See also: "[In .vimrc how to test for passed filename arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256884/in-vimrc-how-to-test-for-passed-filename-arguments)".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you always have a buffer when you're running Vim.  It sounds like the check you really want to do is based on whether file arguments were given to Vim, and thus the args list is empty.  For that, you can use the argc function.

```
if argc() == 0
    ...
endif
```

Comment: Maybe checking `buffer_number("$")` against 1 is another option.

Comment: Thanks. Theoretically it could fail if I launch `vim` with some options, but I can't remember having ever used any options.

Comment: @XavierT., No, the argc function just tells you how long Vim's internal args list is (c.f., :help arglist) so options won't have an effect on that.

Comment: @jamessan: Ah it is nice, so it is definitely the right solution !

Comment: If you use vim as a pager then argc is 0 too, which might be surprising... `echo hi | vim -`