# Restoring the last open Vim session using the sessionman.vim plugin

Tags: session, vim

In my `.vimrc` I have the following configuration:

```
" Sessionman
set viminfo='100,<500,s10,h,!
autocmd VimEnter * SessionOpenLast
let sessionman_save_on_exit = 1
```

But when I try to open file by running

```
$ vim some_file.rb
```

the above command restores the last open session, still.

I would like to configure Vim so that, for such invocations,
it will open the `some_file.rb` file, instead.
How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of "[In .vimrc how to test for passed filename arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6256884/254635)"

Comment: sessionman_save_on_exit doens't work for me :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the provided configuration snippet, the last open session
is restored unconditionally. In order to load the session only when
there are no files supplied as command line arguments, check the
number of arguments (using the `argc()` function) first:

```
:autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 | SessionOpenLast | endif
```

Comment: I'm getting errors:
Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*":
E488: Trailing characters:  SessionOpenLast | endif